# Magento Products Ordered Report

Tags: magento

I'm struggling with the Magento report for "Products Ordered".

Is the `Ordered Quantity` affected by the date filter? Why do some of the products show as 0? Where does Magento keep the ordered_qty data? I am using Magento 1.4.0.1.

Answer (score 0):

Magento keeps record of all items sold in `sales_order_entity`, which you can retrieve like this:

```
select * from sales_order_entity where 
    entity_type_id = (select entity_type_id from eav_entity_type where 
        entity_type_code = 'sales/order_item'
    );
```

By grouping by entity_id and counting the result, you can get an accurate total of the quantity_sold for a date range. You can see how Magento does this in `Mage_Reports_Model_Mysql4_Order_Collection`. From the code, it appears that Magento does in fact respect the date parameter.

Just to be clear, this means that there is no *single* place where you can retrieve an "ordered_qty" number without more complex queries. The most obvious reason some products show as 0 is that they haven't sold anything.

Comment: in v1.4 and up, the table is `sales_flat_order`, so the query shuold be `select * from sales_flat_order where entity_type_id = (select entity_type_id from eav_entity_type where entity_type_code = 'sales/order_item' );`

Answer (score 0):

In v1.4 and up, you should be able to query the `sales_flat_order_item` table and then group and sum on qty_ordered.  e.g.

```
select product_id, sku, sum(`qty_ordered`) from sales_flat_order_item group by product_id
```

Cheers,
JD